# How does shape of a wavefunction changes as it encounters a potential barrier?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wave-particle-duality, quantum-tunneling

A particle of mass and energy $E > 0$ in one dimension is scattered by the potential
below

[image]

If the particle was moving from $x = -\infty$ to $x= +\infty$, which of the following graphs gives
the best qualitative representation of the wavefunction of this particle?

[image]

In the book, option (c) is given as the correct answer.

My interpretation of the answer is that in the region $a<x<b$, the particle's kinetic energy will continuously increase due to the increasing negative potential from a to b. Consequently, the wavelength in the region from a to b will shrink continuously.

Although the particle's energy is greater than the potential, still there will be a finite probability of the particle being reflected at the boundary (a) and throughout the region from a to b. Therefore, the amplitude of the wavefunction keeps decreasing from a to b.

Is my interpretation correct? If not, please help me understand.

Comment: you should give a reference for your quotes. The figures seem strange to me. according to this link http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html the wavefunction is in a decay form in the barrier.

Comment: @annav It isn't a barrier. The potential _decreases_ (becomes negative) between A and B. And it was specified that the particle has energy >0